# Closures - use of moved value

Tags: compiler-errors, closures, rust

I am currently trying to work with the [iron](https://github.com/iron/iron) framework. I am using their middleware [router](https://github.com/iron/router). My problem now is that I have a variable called `default_data` which i want to use by default. From earlier research, I know that I have to use the `move` keyword in my closures. This however yields a problem with my `default_data` variable which gets unavailable for any other closures after the first one has been added to the router.

This is roughly how the part of my code looks like:

```
let mut router = Router::new();
let default_data = std::collections::BTreeMap::<String, String>::new();
default_data.insert("test".to_string(), "data".to_string());

router.get("/", move |_| {
  let mut new_data = default_data.clone();
  new_data.insert("test2".to_string(), "some other data".to_string());
  Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, new_data.get("test2".to_string()).unwrap())))
}

router.get("/test", move |_| {
  let mut new_data = default_data.clone();
  new_data.insert("test2".to_string(), "some other data again".to_string());
  Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, new_data.get("test".to_string()).unwrap())))
}
```

The Error I get is `E0382`, `capture of moved value: 'some_data'`. I kind of know the problem but I dont really know how to solve this one. Im still pretty new to rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're okay with cloning this `default_data` before sending it to each thread, right? Then you just need to clone it *outside* of the closure:

```
let mut router = Router::new();
let default_data = BTreeMap::new();
default_data.insert("test".to_owned(), "data".to_owned());

{
    let mut new_data = default_data.clone();
    router.get("/", move |_| {
        new_data.insert("test2".to_owned(), "some other data".to_owned());
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, new_data.get("test2".to_owned()).unwrap())))
    });
}

{
    let mut new_data = default_data.clone();
    router.get("/test", move |_| {
        new_data.insert("test2".to_owned(), "some other data again".to_owned());
        Ok(Response::with((status::Ok, new_data.get("test".to_owned()).unwrap())))
    });
}
```

Comment: For this case it would work I guess but the data won't always be the same. I always want to use the `default_data` as my "skeleton" though. I guess I would run into problems as soon as I need the data to be different in the same closure (imagine displaying some user's "dashboard", the info would be personalized and not equal for all users).

Comment: I think I came up with something: since I need to create new BTreeMaps anyway, I could just make a function that always inserts the data into the TreeMap. Guess that would be the easiest way, unless someone else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Yes, I'd say that would be the most natural way to do it - a function like `fn make_default_data() -> BTreeMap<String, String>`.